# How to add lines between JTable rows?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable and could not make visible the lines between rows or maybe there is no line, I am not sure. Here is my JTable:

[image: My JTable]

How can I make it look like this?

[image: Other one]

Here is my code:

```
public class NodePropertyWindow extends JFrame{

public NodePropertyWindow(CytoVisProject cytoVisProject, CyNode node){
    this.cytoVisProject = cytoVisProject;
    this.adapter = cytoVisProject.getAdapter();
    this.node = node;
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
    this.setTitle("Node Property Window");
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.initializeTable();
}

public void initializeTable(){
    CyApplicationManager manager = this.adapter.getCyApplicationManager();
    CyNetworkView networkView = manager.getCurrentNetworkView();
    CyNetwork network = networkView.getModel();
    CyTable cyTable = network.getDefaultNodeTable();

    FilterUtil filterUtil = new FilterUtil(network, cyTable);
    Map<String, Object> sampleRow = cyTable.getAllRows().get(filterUtil.findIndex(filterUtil.getAllNodes(), node)).getAllValues();
    Collection<Object> values = sampleRow.values();
    Set<String> attributeNames = sampleRow.keySet();

    String[] columnNames = {"Attribute Name", "Value"};
    this.data = new Object[values.size()][2];
    Object[] attributeNamesObjects = attributeNames.toArray();
    Iterator iterator = values.iterator();

    for(i=0; i<values.size(); i++){
        this.data[i][0] = attributeNamesObjects[i];
        Object object = iterator.next();
        this.data[i][1] = object;

    }
    // Above part is about the content of JTable
    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(this.data, columnNames){
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
            return false;
        }
    };

    this.table = new JTable(this.data, columnNames);
    this.table.setModel(model);
    this.table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,300));
    this.table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    this.table.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Container container = new Container();
    container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    container.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    container.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(container);
}
}
```

This part is inside of a class which extends JFrame.

Comment: Start by looking at [How to use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). I believe this is the look and feel used by the way

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AxelH Thanks, I read it but could not find the answer there.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks, I just updated my code.

Comment: Perhaps use the **JTable.setGridColor()** method and the **JTable.setShowGrid()** method.

Comment: @DevilsHnd This solved my problem. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @JollyRoger, `this.table.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` - don't attempt to set a layout manager on a JTable.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this one. I choose black color because Jtable gridlines are white as the default color.

```
table.setGridColor(Color.BLACK)
```